# MS Outlook attatchment sync with Sharepoint database

Tags: vba, sharepoint, outlook, archive

Okay this might be a interesting question but if there is a custom form people use on Outlook to submit files to be posted online, is there anyway (when the send button is pressed) to sync that file to a Sharepoint database (archive) of these file types?

These files are generally reports and we are trying to keep an archive of them without making it a two step process - 1. submit web request 2. then upload to archive.

Comment: Can u explain in brief.

Comment: The custom form is used to be sent to IT in order for documents such as reports or research to be posted online, maybe with a short description etc. The user just hits the attach item button to put the file with the email then sends it to IT. When they hit send I was wondering if it is possible to save this attachment and post it to one of the sharepoint folders we have for archives.

Answer (score 0):

The short but unhelfpful answer is - yes, you can do that.  There are several APIs available for integrating with SharePoint that provide the ability to upload files.  You can build this functionality in an Outlook COM Add-in.  However, a lot more specifics are required for a more detailed answer.

Comment: Okay, I have found some guides about posting to Sharepoint with the VBA code but not sure about grabbing the attachment after it is sent.  What specifics are you looking for?

Comment: You can access Attachment objects from the MailItem.Attachments collection during the MailItem.Send event. Call Attachment.Save and les voila!

Comment: So then I could use this code to save it as an item and upload to the sharepoint server using some more VBA code

Comment: Yup, pretty much. One small correction: use Attachment.SaveAsFile.